# Sequential jQuery animations in 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I’m having trouble with triggering sequential animations using jQuery 1.7.2. There are a bunch of other questions about this on here but they all seem to break if you use a recent version of jQuery implying that the API changed.

I have zero-to-many elements that I want to animate a fade in on sequentially. My current code looks something like:

```
var divs = $('div');
divs.css('opacity',0);
divs.animate({
  opacity: 1
},{
  duration: 1000,
  queue: 'myQueue'
});
```

With jQuery 1.7’s introduction of named queues I’d somewhat naïvely assumed that this would queue up an animation for each element onto a named queue and then execute it, but obviously this isn’t working.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVVzE/1/)

```
$('div').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i + 1) * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan! That works, and more simply than I was expecting. I’d still like to find out how named queues worked so I’m going to see if anyone’s got an answer specific to that, but if not then I’ll accept yours.

Comment: `.queue()` is intended to run several animation effects one after another on a *single* element, not one animation sequentially on multiple elements. You can run the queue on a set of matched elements, but they will happen at the same time - http://jsfiddle.net/JdheJ/